# Get access to a variable in an earlier promise downstream

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Essentially in the script below I would like to know what URL was requested that caused the failed state.

Will I need to encapsulate that in an object and continue to pass it downstream?

```
var Q = require('q')
var _ = require('underscore')
var JSON = require('JSON')
var FS = require("q-io/fs");
var HTTP = require("q-io/http");


FS.read('members.json').then(function(memberJson){
    return JSON.parse(memberJson)
}).then(function(memberObjects){

    var httpCheckPromises = _.chain(memberObjects)
        .first(50)
        .filter(function(member){
            return member.website.toLowerCase().indexOf('www') >= 0
        })
        .map(function(member){
            return HTTP.read(member.website)
        })
        .value()

    return Q.allSettled(httpCheckPromises)

}).then(function(responses){

    return  _.chain(responses)
        .where({state:'rejected'})
        .pluck('reason')
        .pluck('response')
        .value() ;

}).then(function(badResponses){

    return _.chain(badResponses)
        .filter(function(response) {
            return response
        })
        .map(function(response){
            return {
                status: response.status
                , headers: response.headers
            }
        })
        .value()

}).then(function(responses){
    return FS.write("members_with_bad_urls.json", JSON.stringify(responses,null,4))
}).then(function(){
    console.log('DONE!')
}).fail(function(reason){
    console.log('FAIL!')
    console.log(reason)
})
```

For example in my second code block add return an object

```
 then(function(memberObjects){

    var httpCheckPromises = _.chain(memberObjects)
        .first(50)
        .filter(function(member){
            return member.website.toLowerCase().indexOf('www') >= 0
        })
        .map(function(member){
            return {
                url: member.website
                ,response: HTTP.read(member.website)
            }
        })
        .value()

    return Q.allSettled(httpCheckPromises)

})
```

But I think I would have issues with the Q.allSettled needing to be rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

Akaphenom, to make results available down the chain, you could always employ one or more outer vars but it is maybe cleaner to use this type of pattern :

```
promise_returning_function().then(function(x) {
    return { x: x } ;//this object will be passed all the way down the .then chain.
}).then(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x
    obj.y = ...;//add result of this process to obj
    //return obj;
}).then(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x and obj.y
    obj.z = ...;//add result of this process to obj
    //return obj;
}).done(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x and obj.y and obj.z
});
```

To illustrate the pattern I just added a single property to `obj` at each stage (as per the code in the question) but you could add as many properties as you want - none, one or more than one - whatever subsequent stages need.

Unfortunately, by propagating `obj` in this way, the power of `.then()` to return a fresh promise is lost. However, the following variant of the pattern overcomes this :

```
promise_returning_function().then(function(x) {
    var promise_x = ...;//do something asynchronous here
    return Q.when(promise_x, function(result_x) {
        return { x: result_x };//this object will be passed all the way down the .then chain.
    });
}).then(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x
    var promise_y = ...;//do something asynchronous here
    return Q.when(promise_y, function(result_y) {
        obj.y = result_y;
        return obj;
    });
}).then(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x and obj.y
    var promise_z = ...;//do something asynchronous here
    return Q.when(promise_z, function(result_z) {
        obj.z = result_z;
        return obj;
    });
}).done(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x and obj.y and obj.z
});
```

*Maybe this pattern could be called a ".then waterfall"?*

The code is rather verbose and an outer `var obj = {};` would certainly be more concise, but hopefully the pattern is of some potential use.

### Edit

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UGsDt/)**, where I've pulled out the repeating code and created a helper function `propagate()`.

### Edit2

And a **[more convincing version of the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UGsDt/1/)** with a setTimeout delay at each stage.

### Edit 3

This is what the pattern looks like with the helper function `propagate()`

```
function propagate(p, obj, prop) {
    return Q.when(p, function(result) {
        obj[prop] = result;
        return obj;
    });
}
promise_returning_function().then(function(x) {
    var promise_x = ...; //do something asynchronous here
    return propagate(promise_x, {}, 'x');
}).then(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x
    var promise_y = ...; //do something asynchronous here
    return propagate(promise_y, obj, 'y');
}).then(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x and obj.y
    var promise_z = ...; //do something asynchronous here
    return propagate(promise_z, obj, 'z');
}).done(function(obj) {
    //here you can read obj.x and obj.y and obj.z
});
```

Comment: Oh man- creative approach and much better than the alternative I was considering.  I have a solution for my current issue (although this approach is better), mentioned in my solution and it side steps this issue.  I am going to leave this open for another day or two to see if we solicit more solutions.  A pattern, may be worth a thousand words.

Comment: This is really a super answer.   The code is clean and it solves a problem I expect will become prominant

Answer (score 0):

I am pulling the original HTTP request out of the response.node.req object that travels along with the request.  Unfortunately - not an answer to my orignial question, but a ssolution to my problem.  Unfortunately II - I am referencing a variable proveeded by an underscore, which leaves me a bit nervous.  OK for a simple script that I am running once - dbut not a great solution.

```
then(function(badResponses){

    return _.chain(badResponses)
        .filter(function(response) {
            return response
        })
        .map(function(response){
            var req = response.node.req

            return {
                requestUri: req._headers.host + req.path
                , httpStatusDesc: friendlyHttpStatus(response.status)
                , httpStatus: response.status
                , movedTo: response.headers.location
            }
        })
        .value()

})
```